# How to use template class with default parameters as argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to prepare some specialized functions for a template class with some arguments. How do I tell `settings` in `print_settings` to accept `testl` as well as `testllb`? How do I announce long*/bool instances and why can't the compiler deduct the correct types for the further types (which are given then)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, T const *a=nullptr, bool const b=false>
class settings {
public:
    friend std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream &os, const settings &set) {
        os << set.min_val();
    }
    T const min_val() const {return a ? *a : -1;};
};

long l0{0};

void print_settings(settings<long> t) {
    std::cout << "INTEGER: " << t.min_val() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    settings<long> testl;
    print_settings(testl);
    settings<long, &l0, true> testllb;
    // print_settings(testllb); // This is failing.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: make it template function or use auto

Comment: Your problem is that `settings<long>` and `settings<long, nullptr, false>` name the exact same type, so `settings<long>` and `settings<long, &l0, true>` name *totally different types*. As Marek suggests, making `print_settings` a template function resolves the issue.  (Unrelated: `settings::operator<<` should return `std::ostream &` and it should also have a return statement.)

Answer (score 0):

`settings<long>` and `settings<long, &l0, true>` are different classes.

Therefore we're going to need an overload for each class.

The easiest way to achieve this is with a template function:

```
template <long const *a, const bool b>
void print_settings(settings<long, a, b> t) {
    std::cout << "INTEGER: " << t.min_val() << std::endl;
}
```